# hook for before each and every scenario

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

i am using an automation framework which uses Cucumber, testng with java. Here i want to execute some clean up steps after each and every cucumber scenario. can any one suggest how to do it. thanks in advance.

Comment: [Do these docs not provide the answer](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) for running after each scenario, 3rd code example? Or are you looking to do something else?

Comment: i am working in java. and with junit i found before and after annotations. But with testng annotations it is running those methods before and after of test annotated methods. But with cucumber we will not give test annotation for the scenarios. i am looking to execute some code before and after every cucumber scenario defined in the features

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is only another execution mechanism to run your cucumber based tests.
The way the Cucumber-TestNG works is like this :

TestNG provides a base class which your test classes essentially subclass and provide the bare essential details such as the location of the feature files, the glue method location as packages, reporters information etc.,

After that TestNG merely executes every Feature that it finds as a data driven test. So if you provided the location to two or more features, those features get executed in sequence.

For your hook needs, you can perhaps refer to the below links :

- https://www.coveros.com/background-and-hooks-for-cucumber-jvm/
- http://eloraparija.com/cucumber-hooks-example/
- http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/

Comment: Have you check the 3rd link?

Answer (score 0):

As i am new to testng i thought before and after annotations wont work with cucumber scenarios.

I am placing the annotated methods inside RunTest class itself. so it is not recognizing those methods. I placed them in another class, now it is working fine.

Thank you guys for your responses.